# Can I set default view mode of a field inside Notebook/Page

Tags: odoo-11

I have overriden `account.invoice_supplier_form` and I have added kanban view

```
    <record id="invoice_supplier_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.supplier.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_supplier_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field[@name='invoice_line_ids']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="mode">tree,kanban</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field[@name='invoice_line_ids']" position="inside">
                <kanban class="o_kanban_mobile">
                   ...
```

So now page inside notebook supports two views - tree and kanban for `invoice_line_ids`. I want to set kanban as default view. How do I do that?

...

Comment: Right now, on big screen monitor I see tree view. I see kanban view when device is small (ipad mini or similar). What I want is, make kanban default everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```xml
 <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field[@name='invoice_line_ids']" position="attributes">
        <!-- reverse the order here -->
        <attribute name="mode">kanban,tree</attribute>
   </xpath>

    <!-- and here make sure the kanban is the first tag inside the field tag -->    
    <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field[@name='invoice_line_ids']/tree" position="before">
        <kanban class="o_kanban_mobile">
        ....
        ....
```